# getting value from input field and open a new link

Tags: javascript, html, href

im completely new to html && javascript coding so now im doing my first steps and trying to write a search bar which will pass google your input text

```
<script src="func.js"></script>
  <form name="googleSeach">
   <p align="center"><input name="searchTxt" id="searchTxt" type=search placeholder="Google Search">
   <input type="submit" value="Find" onclick="test()"></p>
  </form>
```

and javascript

```
function test(){
    window.open("https://www.google.ru/webhp?newwindow=#q="+document.getElementById('searchTxt').value,"_self")
}
```

well, thought it should work but no, it does not. What's the proble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe you just want to use

```
<form name="googleSeach" onsubmit="test(event)">
```

Instead of onclick.

Also your handler should probably cancel the submit action. Also use `location.href` instead of `window.open` since you're trying to open the new URL in the same window.

http://jsfiddle.net/bvaughn/fr35mpgf/2/

Comment: ;) Sorry for rushing it the first time